# Any Suggestions for Opening a .asc (ASCII) file when Notepad doesn't do the trick?

Tags: file, ascii, notepad

I was attempting to open a raw data file (.asc) format with Notepad and am getting gibberish like the following:

1A120090900007 01Piedmont Federal Savings Bank        16 W 3rd St
00   02 1F120090900007 CCR134 +0000000000CCR180

Now, I tried searching around as to what this formatting might be but haven't been able to find anything (thought it might be ActionScript but I doubt it).

Does anyone recognize this formatting or know why it may not be opening properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's a raw data file, as you suggested, that might be correct. That's probably a fixed-width data format of some type, although you'd have to ask the creators what the format was.

It looks like **20090900007** probably represents a date/time, followed by an address and other domain-specific data.

Comment: I think you are right, asking the creator of the file may be the easiest (it's NTIS which probably won't be that easy but I can hope).

Answer (score 0):

That could be someone's bank account number and routing number on the second line.

This is probably just some form data, and not intended to be human readable.